# How can I interface with the Perl debugger API?

Tags: perl, api, interface, debugging

Is there a way to interface the Perl debugger API which perl is using to control its debugging programmatically?

Comment: I really hate comments like this.  Boo hoo, you lose 15 points, the best answer still floats to the top, and that loss is offset by two votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all in the [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html), [perldebguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebguts.html), and [DB](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB.html) documentation.

In addition, I've written a [Creating a Perl Debugger](http://www.ddj.com/184404522) which should get you started. I have a section on custom Perl debuggers in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/) too.

Answer (score 5):

The default Perl debugger was not designed with a clean API to interact with, so the easiest way is probably not to use it, but to use [Devel::ebug](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-ebug/), which offers an API to an alternative debugger. You can also trigger the debugger from inside your code, calling an interactive debugger session, with [Enbugger](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Enbugger/).

Comment: who does open perl ide does it ? 
its free ide in sf.net

Comment: IMHO, it is better to use Eclipse or Padre instead of Open Perl IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the perl debugger at [perldoc perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) and [perldoc perldebtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html).  You can invoke the debugger with the `-d` option, i.e. `perl -d myscript.pl`.

Answer (score 0):

See "Programming Perl" 20.5.1 -> "Writing your own debugger", 
also see perldoc perlvar $PERLDB.

What you want to do is to implement the DB::DB() sub.